# How do the vampires in Buffy know how to fight?

Tags: vampire, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy, the slayer has to have super human strength in order to fight vampires. We know that the vampires don't have fighting skills before they are turned.
In the episode Gingerbread, Joyce sees a vampire and says

> It's Mr. Sanderson from the bank! -[buffyworld script](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/045_scri.html)

Dawn even makes a comment about their fighting skills in the episode Lessons when she's about to fight a vampire coming out of it's grave

> But, he's new. He
>   doesn't know his strength. He-he might not know those fancy martial
>   art skills they inevitably seem to pick up. -[Buffy Guide Quotes](http://www.buffyguide.com/episodes/lessons/lessonsquotes.shtml)

Where do the vampires learn how to fight?

Comment: “We know that the vampires don't have fighting skills before they are turned. In the episode Gingerbread, Joyce sees a vampire and says ‘It's Mr. Sanderson from the bank!’” For all we know, Mr Sanderson from the bank was a black belt; people do have hobbies.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging

Comment: As a martial artist currently making my way through Buffy for the first time (I haven't gotten to "Lessons" yet), I was about to snarkily say "they don't."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The general rule of thumb with the Buffy-verse is that when someone becomes a vampire, the body's original inhabitant takes a hike (their soul travels to heaven or hell) and a demon then inhabits their dead body.

It follows that the martial arts skills of the newly hosted vampire are those of the demon, augmented by whatever skill the original owner had.

> **Buffy:**  (looks down at the people) *These people aren't gonna get  changed, are they? The rest of them, they're just fodder.*
>
> **Ford:**  *Technically, yes. But I'm in. I will become immortal.*
>
> **Buffy:**  *Well, I've got a news flash for you, braintrust: that's not how  it works. You die, and a demon sets up shop in your old
>   house, and it  walks, and it talks, and it remembers your life, but
>   it's not you.* - <sup><sub>[Buffy: Lie to Me](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/transcripts/019_tran.html)</sub></sup>

It's worth noting that some vampires are far more influenced by the body's owner than others. Harmony, for instance seems almost human (aside from being evil) with the same deep interest in fashion and an *almost pathological inability to fight properly.*

Comment: The last paragraph may be speculative. Perhaps the demon that comes to inhabit the body is "chosen" by their affinity with the original owner's personality. So it is not that Harmony influenced the demon, the demon that took interest for Harmony's body had similar tastes.

Comment: Maybe Harm's demon is just particularly smart, because being bad at fighting gave her significantly more life time around Buffy than most other vampires managed.

Comment: @nwp - It led her to a range of self-destructive behaviours though, joining the vamp cult, creating her own gang to kill the slayer, attacking Buffy through Dawn, etc etc.

Comment: if the original owner of the body is gone then why Buffy-vampire is not evil in [S01E10: Nightmares](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/transcripts/010_tran.html) -- she has a bloodlust but she behaves as herself otherwise?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Because the dreams are being manifested by a small boy. My guess is that since he has limited experience of vampires, he's basing it on Buffy's own fear about what being a vampire would be like. She's not a *real* vampire, she's a caricature of one.

Comment: @Richard: the nightmares themselves and elements in them are unknown by Billy. The boy makes the nightmares real regardless of their content, he doesn't control the specifics. A possible explanation: Buffy's nightmare is NOT that she becomes a vampire and the demon occupying her body slaughters her friends.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Perhaps Buffy's nightmare is that she'll start *acting* like a vampire.

Comment: Yes, whatever the actual position, Buffy's nightmare doesn't have to be true to it.  She may even at the time have believed the thing about vampires being demons and not the original person (though she had heard Angel's story by that time - that'd be pretty good extra nightmare fuel, literally).  But nightmares aren't always logical.  If what she was picturing was how awful it would be if she, herself, was a vampire and going to kill people, that's what she'd get, whether that was normally possible or not.

Comment: -1.  I don't think this actually is how it's supposed to work.  Buffy said that, yes, but how would she know?  Angel, in both states, always seemed to take it as read that he was the same person throughout the proceedings, and he ought to know if anyone would.  So did Spike when he told Buffy about how he became a vampire, he referred to himself as "me" throughout: "I've never felt so alive as when I died".  To me, they come across as the original human minds that have been crudely hot-wired: their sense or right and wrong is amputated and some kind of predatory instinct (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) added, but otherwise it's the same person.  You could say that if it's magic it might as well give them fighting skills at the same time - but I don't think it does, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## They don't.

I don't think they are supposed to start out with any fighting skills, unless they had them as humans.  There are quite a few examples in the series of newly turned vampires that are plain incompetent.  The episode mentioned in the question, "Lessons", spells this out a bit in the bit quoted in the question, and a few lines later, there's also this.

> **Buffy:** He's a vampire, OK? Demon. Preternaturally strong. Skilled with powers no human could possibly ever—
>
> **Vampire** *(trying to get out of his grave)***:** Excuse me. I think I'm stuck.

Their demon blood gives the vampires superhuman speed, strength and some kind of predatory instinct.  That makes them dangerous to ordinary humans even if they're just lunging randomly.  But a newly turned vampire is no trouble to Buffy, and even the rest of the gang stand a chance against them once they've actually had some training.  Experienced vampires (for instance, Darla, The Three, Drusilla, or Spike) are shown as much more of a challenge.  If the vampires survive long enough, *then* they can start learning the best way to fight.

I'm rather thinking that Harmony's continued incompetence demonstrates this - a vampire has to *practise* to learn to fight, the same as anyone else, and I can't imagine Harmony practising her martial arts skills when there are gossip magazines to be read.  I imagine Spike tried to teach her at some point.  I imagine he gave up in despair pretty soon.